# Is it possible to edit the .bash_login file for the second time?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I accidentally wrote an error command in the `.bash_login` file. I need to edit the file to solve this problem but I can't do that anymore. The error is about the `.bash_login` isn't a writable file (read-only file).

Is it possible to edit the `.bash_login` file for the second time?
Or simply edit the permission of that file?

I've discover that change the file permission is same as write something into the file so I can't do that with the `chmod`.

Thank a lot in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `stat .bash_login`? Also `chmod` isn't quite the same as writing to the file, so you should be able to use it (unless the problem is something else)

Comment: @muru the output of `stat .bash_login` is:
  File: '.bash_login'
  Size: 53  Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d Inode: 540642 Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid: (   0/  root)  Gid: (  0/  root)
Access: 2015-04-27 06:21:58.825162772 +0200
Modify: 2015-04-23 11:52:22.750314367 +0200
Change: 2015-04-23 11:52:22.750314367 +0200
 Birth: -

I've try that many times but the `chmod ` still can't change the persmissions. I do this on the recovery mode, with the root user. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is owned by root. You should be using `chown` instead:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER .bash_login
```

Comment: Still fail. Output:
`chown: changing ownership of '.bash_login': Read-only file system`

Comment: @Andromeda are you in recovery mode?

Comment: @Andromeda Follow steps 8 and 9 from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: @Andromeda and replace `$USER` with your username.

Comment: Actually, I ever try step by step on that wiki page, but unfortunately fail. I forget what was wrong on that time. However, now I try again as you suggest to do that and it worked successfully. Now the problem is solved. Thanks a lot, Sir.